# How can I use a loop in LESS to create specific class names for typography?

Tags: css, sass, less

I want to generate 9 typography classes, each with the following:

```
font-size: 2rem;
line-height: 1rem;
```

I'll be using standard typographic multipliers for font sizes and line-height. Instead of hard-coding all of these CSS classes, I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of generating them in a loop using LESS.

I found the following from another thread:

```
@iterations: 5;
.span-loop (@i) when (@i > 0) {
    .span-@{i} {
        width: ~"@{i}%";
    }
    .span-loop(@i - 1);
}
.span-loop (@iterations);
```

Which generates:

```
.span-5 {
  width: 5%;
}
.span-4 {
  width: 4%;
}
.span-3 {
  width: 3%;
}
.span-2 {
  width: 2%;
}
.span-1 {
  width: 1%;
}
```

This is pretty close, but I'd love for my class names to more "named". How can I use a loop to generate classes for:

```
.small { }
.caption { }
.body { }
.subheader { }
.title { }
.headline { }
```

etc...

I'm also not tied to LESS, so if there's a better CSS preprocessor language, then I'm happy to use that instead :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example from documentation for further modification;)
for more complicated code, it is better to use scss than less

```
.for(@list, @code) {
  & {
    .loop(@i: 1) when (@i =< length(@list)) {
      @value: extract(@list, @i);
      @code();
      .loop(@i + 1);
    }
    .loop();
  }
}

@elements: small, caption, body, subheader, title, headline;

.for(@elements, {
  @remfont: @i+1;
  @remline: ((@i+1) * 1.5 / 3);
  .@{value} {
    font-size: ~"@{remfont}rem";
    line-height: ~"@{remline}rem";
  }
});
```

Comment: From which documentation have you taken this?

Comment: @BairDev First, look at the date I added it and answer yourself if you remember what you did on June 30, 2019 :) The documentation is probably less documentation.